# gradle: exclude folders from the resources of a dependency

Tags: gradle

Is there a way to exclude folders from the resources of a dependency using gradle?
I am trying to exclude **resources/domains** and **resources/views** folders of this implementation

```
implementation "com.tobris:tobris-core:${openPlatformVersion}-SNAPSHOT"
```